# Trouble with eval of a sentence as input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am in a class teaching python and am a beginner at any sort of coding. I keep running into this problem and I can't find anything in my text book or additional handouts explaining what I'm doing wrong. Here is an example taken from one of the exercises that I am having trouble with. The task is to write a program that takes a sentence given by the user and rearrange the words to get "yoda speak". This is what I have.

```
def main():

    print("Enter a sentence and have it translated into Yoda speak!")

    sentence= eval(input("Enter your sentence: "))
    word_list=sentence.split()

    yoda_words= word_list[2:]+word_list[0:2]

    yoda_says= yoda_words.join()

    print("Yoda says: ", yoda_says)

main()
```

However why I try to run the program I get this:

Enter a sentence and have it translated into Yoda speak!

Enter your sentence: Jane ran fast

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.0\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 14, in 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.0\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 5, in main
  File "", line 1, in ?
Syntax Error: Jane ran fast: , line 18

I think the problem comes from me using the whole eval(input()) command wrong. Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What do you expect `eval` to do? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace your input statement with the following (see note 1):

```
sentance= input("Enter your sentence: ")
```

Also, try this for your join:

```
' '.join(yoda_words)
```

(note 1) As pointed out by @Boud below, better to use `input` (instead of raw_input with Python 2.x) with Python 3.x (see for example [What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4915361/1209279))

I currently don't have access to Python 3.x - really should install it.

Comment: @Boud Thanks for pointing this out .. I should really start working with Python 3.x

Answer (score 4):

`eval` runs Python code, e.g. eval("1+1") returns 2, this is not what you want. This is the reason you get the syntax error on "Jane ran fast", Python is trying to execute `Jane ran fast`.

Remove the `eval` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The *eval* is unnecessary.  Remove it and all should work fine.  That just leaves fixing the spelling of "sentance" :-)